# How to scrape tweets from twitter using java

Tags: java, eclipse, twitter, web-scraping

I need to scrape tweets of a celebrity.Can this be done? I was able to use JSoup to scrape data from wikipedia. I tried the same way for twitter and ended up with the following errors.I guess I dont have the permissions to do so.Is there a different API that I can use? I am new to web scraping. Please help.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:   
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid
certification path to requested target
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: you could probably use [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html). Never used it, but I'm sure you could get something from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Java source code for the [microblog proxy server](https://github.com/vitaldatalink/microblog/tree/master/server/src/main/java/microblog/provider/twitter), a web service which parses the messages and images from Twitter.  It uses **twitter4j** for private Twitter.  For public Twitter, it uses **Jsoup** to do web scraping.